# OpenCV: getting incorrect result in calculating the distance between object and the center of picture

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am new to this area and I was assigned a project that using a raspberry pi to control a robot.

I wrote a python program in Raspberry Pi with a camera (resolution is 1280*960), the program is using the camera to capture a picture that contains a red color object as a reference point to calculate the distance to other destination (because the waypoint of robot arm somehow is different every time I turned on the arm).

Here are my parameters:

actual size of object: 25mm (width) * 20mm (length)
pixel of Object ≈ 133 pixels * 108 pixels

Center of the picture: (640, 480)
Center of the object: (128, 331)

Pixel distance per mm (x-axis) = Object pixel width / Actual width = 133 pixels / 25 mm = 5.32

the x-distance between the centers:

Pixel distance (x-direction) = 640 - 128 = 512
Actual distance (x-direction) = 512 / 5.32 ≈ 96.24mm

Therefore I expect the actual distance is 96.24mm, however, the real actual distance is 102mm.

I have checked the equation many times and I can confirm the conversion factor is correct since the length of the object is calculated correctly.

Does anyone know why the result is not correct with the actual distance?

I can provide the code I wrote if you need it!

I would like to know why the result is not correct with the actual distance.

Comment: Did you calibrate the image: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html ?

Comment: Add some pictures to make it easier to understand for others. It's not clear what is the situation.